# Catch exception in C++ Form

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am new to C++. I am trying to make a program in C++, but I get an error, when I use `e.what()`. I've included `#include <exception>`, but I get `error C2664 - Cannot convert parameter 1 from const char* to system::string ^`.

Here's the code.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

namespace SilverthorneTechnologiesSchoolDashboard {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;

//Form parameters

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        ifstream codeFile;
        try{
            codeFile.open("userDetails.info");
        }
        catch (exception &e)
        {
            label1->Text = e.what();
        }
         }
 };
}
```

Comment: You need to tag this as another language, because it isn't C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codeFile` is unmanaged code, throwing an unmanaged exception, so you're catching the exception properly. All you need to do is convert the `const char *` to a `String^` to put it in your UI.

The [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class has a constructor that takes a [`char*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s9t975.aspx) (char* is SByte* in C#). `label1->Text = gcnew String(e.what());`  should solve your problem.

That said, you could use the managed stream objects. This would give you managed exceptions instead of unmanaged, and greater interoperability with the rest of your managed code. Take a look at [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), and see if that meets your needs.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a guess but try changing

```
catch (exception &e)
```

to

```
catch (exception& e)
```